# can't access database after all activities are closed

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite

My android app requires updation of database in every 30 minutes.I used `scheduleAtFixedRate()`
for it.But the problem is after some time app closes and shows an error `connection pool closed` the scheduleatfixedrate() is written in a service class.

Please anybody suggest me a safe way to update database in regular interval of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a singelton database connection in your service and method for check open db.